# How to calculate total price using java script and pop out the total price

Tags: javascript, html

how I am supposed to write some code which gets the values of all the selected checkboxes, adds them up, and then adds on the value of the selected size as well

this is my code for html. I am still dint figure yet for the java script part

```html
<form name="order_submit" method="post" action="" onSubmit="">
  <h1>My Pizza Cafe</h1>
  <br>


  <h3>Step 2: Select the pizza you want:</h3>

  <input type="radio" name="pizza" value="15">Small
  <input type="radio" name="pizza" value="20">Medium
  <input type="radio" name="pizza" value="25">Large


  <h3>Step 3: Select the topping you want:</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="5" onclick="onlyOne(this)"> Pepperoni
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="7" onclick="onlyOne(this)"> Sausage
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="5" onclick="onlyOne(this)"> Mushroom <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="4" onclick="onlyOne(this)"> Pineapple
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="4" onclick="onlyOne(this)"> Black Olives
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="7" onclick="onlyOne(this)"> Meatball
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Order">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear Entries">

</form>
```

Comment: What? Could you please add more details...

Comment: Where is the code for the JS functions you've specified here? What do you want each function to do? What have you tried so far? What specific problem are you experiencing (e.g. an error, or incorrect output)? We'd like to _help_ you, but this is not just a free write-my-code service. You should at least be able to attempt something like this yourself. Did you forget to add your JS code?

Comment: and add the definition of the `onlyOne` function. It causes an error when trying to interact with your example

Comment: I mean the basic answer to your question "how I am supposed to" is... "write some code which gets the values of all the selected checkboxes, adds them up, and then adds on the value of the selected size as well". Have you attempted to do that? The logic isn't difficult, as you can see...and you can easily research online how to get the values of selected elements in your code in order to do the maths on them, so it's unclear what precisely is causing you a difficulty. If you can clarify what exactly in the code you want help with, we'll gladly help you.

Comment: @ADyson thank you what you said is totally correct, As I managed to do it, I Just got wrong idea for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go (with jQuery). Add when checked, subtract when unchecked again.
Error handling etc. is up to you

This is a mix out of different solution ideas:

- Always update the current value (as done here with the toppings). This is useful when you want to display the current total
- Calculate the sum when the form is submitted. Then you need to iterate through all checked checkboxes and sum up their values.

```js
let toppingsValue = 0;

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    toppingsValue += parseInt(this.value);
  } else {
    toppingsValue -= parseInt(this.value);
  }
});

$("form").submit(() => {
  const selectedPizza = $("input[name='pizza']:checked");
  const total = toppingsValue + parseInt(selectedPizza.val());
  alert("total: " + total);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="order_submit" method="post" action="">
  <h1>My Pizza Cafe</h1>
  <br>


  <h3>Step 2: Select the pizza you want:</h3>

  <input type="radio" name="pizza" value="15">Small
  <input type="radio" name="pizza" value="20">Medium
  <input type="radio" name="pizza" value="25">Large


  <h3>Step 3: Select the topping you want:</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="5"> Pepperoni
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="7"> Sausage
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="5"> Mushroom <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="4"> Pineapple
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="4"> Black Olives
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="7"> Meatball
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Order">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear Entries">

</form>
```